# Spring WebTestClient bindToController usage

Tags: spring, unit-testing, webclient

I am trying to figure out how to use WebTestClient.bindToController().

I have the following 2 classes:

- Controller
- Service

Controller.methodx() calls Service.methody(). Service.methody() calls an external REST POST end point.

How would I use WebTestClient.bindToController() to test this Controller? I couldn't find a lot of usage information online.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;


@PostMapping(value="/customer", consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Mono<Customer> saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
    return this.customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService implements ICustomerService {


@Autowired  
private WebClient webClient;      


@Override
public Mono<Customer> storeMessage(Customer cust) {

     Mono<Customer> resp = this.webClient.post() 
              .uri("/postdata")
              .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(customer))
              .exchange();

    return resp
}

}
```

CONFIG:

```
@Configuration
public class ProdConfig {


@Bean
public ICustomerService getCustomerService() {
    return new CustomerService();
}

@Bean
public WebClient getWebClient() {

    return WebClient.builder()
              .baseUrl("baseurl")
              .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MIME_TYPE)
              .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
              .build();
}

}
```

TestClass:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc

public class CustomerControllerTest {

 @MockBean
 private CustomerService customerservice;

 private WebTestClient testClient;

 @Test
 public void testSaveCustomer() throws Exception {       
    testClient= WebTestClient.bindToController(new CustomerController(customerService)).build();

    testClient.post().uri("/customer").body(BodyInserters.fromObject(customer))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();
 }
}
```

TESTCONFIG:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {


@Bean
public WebClient getWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
              .baseUrl("baseurl")
              .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MIME_TYPE)
              .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT)
              .build();
}

}
```

Error when running test class:

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager[0;39m: Caught exception while invoking 'afterTestMethod' callback on 
TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@61df66b6] for test method 
[public void CustomerControllerTest.testSaveCustomer()] and test instance 
[CustomerControllerTest@22da200e]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

> WebTestClient internally uses WebClient to perform requests.
>   Instead of providing a base url to make the request, we can simply bind the controller to the WebTestClient to handle the request mappings.

CustomerController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class CustomerController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerController( CustomerService customerService) {
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/customer", consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public Mono<Customer> saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        return this.customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
    }
```

CustomerControllerTest.java

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerControllerRestTest {


    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        //mock service here
    }



    @Test
    public void  testSaveCustomer() throws Exception {

        Customer customer = new Customer(1L, "test", CustomerGender.MALE);
        testClient= WebTestClient.bindToController(new CustomerController(customerService)).build();

        testClient.post().uri("/customer").body(BodyInserters.fromObject(customer))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();


    }

}
```

Comment: my object dependencies are slightly different than your example. When I setup my test class like you suggested I get an error. I will edit my post to add the details.

Comment: Problem is with your dependencies, use spring boot 2.x.x.

Comment: my spring boot version is 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: It's because of class path dependencies issue. Check your pom